# Remove text from around DOM node

Tags: javascript

I've selected a DOM node, and I want to do some processing if it is both immediately prefixed and suffixed with a `$`. So, selecting on `<code>` elements, I want to handle this case:

```html
<p>I assert $<code>1 + 1 = 2</code>$, it's true!</p>
```

and turn it into this:

```html
<p>I assert <code class="language-inline-math">1 + 1 = 2</code>, it's true!</p>
```

That is, if my selected DOM node is immediately preceded by some token and immediately succeeded by some token, I want to strip those tokens and do some processing on the node.

I have this working by manipulating `innerHTML`/`outerHTML`, but it feels wrong to be manipulating the DOM elements via the serialized HTML rather than the DOM API. Is there a method to accomplish this without writing to `innerHTML`?

```
// given a pre-selected `var el` DOM node
var parent = el.parentNode;
var inlineMath = "$" + el.outerHTML + "$";
if (parent.innerHTML.indexOf(inlineMath) !== -1) {
    el.classList.add("language-inline-math");
    parent.innerHTML = parent.innerHTML.replace("$" + el.outerHTML + "$", el.outerHTML);
}
```

---

To avoid the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/372348), here's the actual task I'm trying to solve:

I have some (commonmark) markdown, and I'd like to introduce a lightweight extension syntax on top of a (commonmark compliant) markdown parser. For block equasions, this is the obvious choice:

````markdown
```math
1 + 1 = 2
```
````

which becomes

```html
<pre><code class="language-math">1 + 1 = 2
</code></pre>
```

per the CommonMark spec. This can easily be found and then fed into a math display library from JavaScript. For inline math, however, the inline code syntax doesn't support the language class addition, so some additional syntax has to be put on top.

The reuse of code blocks is semantically useful, as they define a span where markdown doesn't do any processing. The common way of handling inline math for LaTeX/MathJax/KaTeX or other systems is via `$`-fencing. So I chose to take GitLab's syntax and use `$ <no space> <inline-code-block> <no space> $` to represent an inline math equation.

Instead of

```markdown
I assert $`1 + 1 = 2`$, it's true!
```

I *could* have people write

```
I assert `$1 + 1 = 2$`, it's true!
```

which *would* have a similar fallback in the event of no JavaScript, but the problem is that `$code$` is something that people want to be able to write normally, thus I prefer the external fencing.

---

Given that I have a working solution, the proper answer may be "there isn't a better way than what you've done already". I feel there is a better way to do this without using the text-based serialized-HTML properties, but it's quite possible that I'm wrong and this is the best way to accomplish this task.

Comment: If you are able to put the tokens in, why not just attach the appropriate class on the code element to begin with? Or maybe add some other class to the elements that need client side processing?

Comment: @JasonB this is a post-process step on a markdown parser's output, so I don't have full control over the resulting HTML. e.g. `$'math'$` (pretend those are backticks) produces an inline `$<code>math</code>$`, but there's no way to attach a class to that node in markdown.

Comment: What happens when using: `'$math$'`? Do you get: `<code>$math$</code>` So you dont care about parent element

Comment: FYI  https://jsperf.com/createtextnode-vs-textcontent-vs-innerhtml-vs-innertext -- https://jsperf.com/innerhtml-vs-createelement-test

Comment: @Andre I could ask people to write e.g. `<math>..</math>` instead of `$'..'$`, but that loses the convenience of reusing markdown code blocks, which semantically works very well (and provides a convenient noscript fallback). I could also replace the suggested `$'..'$` syntax with `'$..$'`, but that has existing semantic meaning (`$..$`) which is useful and I don't want to override.

Comment: What about: `$(':contains("$") > code').filter(function () { doSomeFilteringToRemoveFalsePositives})`

Comment: @Andre Though that would reduce the number of code tags to process somewhat, this check would still have to be done to avoid all false positives (as it wouldn't be uncommon to both use inline math and inline code in a paragraph), and the "hard" part of removing the tokens isn't effected by that selection at all.

Comment: @marekful I'm not exactly sure how to interpret those microbenchmarks. It looks like they contradict each other on what option is better? Though it does seem to make it clear that this isn't as catastrophic towards performance as I feared it might be; browsers have been optimizing this kind of thing for a while.

Comment: Well, the first test answers your question "Is there a method to accomplish this without writing to innerHTML?" Yes there is, and performance-wise you are much better off with assigning new value to `.textContent`.

Comment: @marekful but assigning to [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) treats the entire content as text (good when it is!), but in this case I have `<p> ... $<code> ... </code>$ ... </p>` and want to keep the `<code>` node intact, which `.textContent`/`.innerText` don't do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `element.previousSibling` and `element.nextSibling` properties to get the text nodes right before and after your element, and check if they end and begin with a `$`. Then you can use the `element.splitText(n)` method to split the text nodes into two nodes: One with the `$`, and one with the rest. Then use the `element.remove()` method to remove the `$` text nodes.

```
        var n = e.nextSibling;
        var p = e.previousSibling;
        if (n && p && /^\$/.test(n.data) && /\$$/.test(p.data)) {
            // Whatever you wanted to do with `e` here.
            n.splitText(1); n.remove();
            p.splitText(p.data.length - 1).remove();
        }
```

(That's what I used here: https://github.com/m-ou-se/rust-horrible-katex-hack/blob/565ffd921d3c0eef2037aef58215c56ba1a09ddc/src/lib.rs#L10-L15)